# Capturing unprocessed / raw microphone data on Android devices

Tags: android, audio, microphone

This is a question in regards with capturing audio content on recent Android devices. I'm working at developing an Android app that must record unprocessed microphone audio. In the process of trying to figure out how this could be achieved, I came across the Android Compatibility Definition Documents (CDDs) which, since version 5.0 (API 21), state that “device implementations that declare android.hardware.microphone MUST allow capture of raw audio content [...]” (see any CDD from 5.0 and higher, under the Audio Recording section : https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd).

On the other hand, I have found that there are several audio sources that can be selected under the MediaRecorder APIs and that in order “To record raw audio select UNPROCESSED. Some devices do not support unprocessed input. Call AudioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_SUPPORT_AUDIO_SOURCE_UNPROCESSED) first to verify it's available” (source : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder). The PROPERTY_SUPPORT_AUDIO_SOURCE_UNPROCESSED property was added in API 24.

Here’s where I would need help : I am confused about the fact that the CDDs indicate that capturing raw data MUST be allowed while the MediaRecorder does not always allow access to it. Perhaps is it that “raw” is not the same as “unprocessed”? Or perhaps this means that raw/unprocessed audio data is for system-level functions only, and not available to third-party developers.

Please note that, when I tested in order to verify if the unprocessed property was available on 3 different Android devices (including the Galaxy S8 with API 26), I never got a positive result.

This being said, can someone clarify why CDDs indicate that capture of raw audio content MUST be available when the unprocessed AudioMagager API property rarely seems to be available. Should I be accessing the raw/unprocessed audio content differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because it must provide it raw doesn't mean that the OS needs to provide it to users.  The must may be for internal use by the framework/OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Android CDDs](https://source.android.com/compatibility/) are for developers intending to port the Android platform to other devices/platforms and maintain cross compatibility for app developers. This means that the standard, lower level Android libraries will be able to access the functionality defined in the CDD, but you won't necessarily be able to.

I managed to find an [example here](https://www.androidcookbook.info/android-media/raw-audio-recording-with-audiorecord.html) from androidcookbook.info that goes through getting raw, uncompressed audio via [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord).

If that doesn't suit your needs then I would 100% recommend checking out [OpenSL ES](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/opensl/opensl-for-android) if you haven't looked at/used it yet. It uses the NDK (in C++) to provide a native interface so latency is much lower and you have access to more functionality for audio processing. Here' google's [audio-echo project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/audio-echo) on GitHub that shows recording and playback in real-time using the native processing route with OpenSL ES.

I am sure you have access to the uncompressed audio by using it. You can pass the information to and from Java / C++ as you wish.